# Headless chrome browser disconnected. This problem may appear when a browser hangs or is closed, or due to network

Tags: jenkins, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, google-chrome-headless

**Version of testcafe** - 1.7.0 and 1.7.1 (most recent)
**Version of chrome** - 78.0.3904.108
**Running env** - Linux

**Running it via Jenkins**
This test job was running absolutely fine for the last 4 months till last week but then started getting browser disconnected error.

**Jenkins testcafe command** - `testcafe -c 3 chromium:headless --headless --no-sandbox --disable-background-networking --disable-default-apps --disable-extensions --disable-gpu --disable-sync --disable-translate --hide-scrollbars --metrics-recording-only --mute-audio --no-first-run --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update {*.js,**/*.js} -e --fixture-meta ${params.TestType}=true --env=${params.TestEnv}"`

**Please note** - When I run tests on my local or via docker, they run well.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM testcafe/testcafe
USER root
RUN npm install
RUN npm install minimist
```

Comment: Does the problem persist if you reduce the concurrency factor to 1?

Comment: Yes still fails

Comment: Could you try replacing the --disable-background-networking flag with --disable-ipc-flooding-protection?

Comment: Thanks @AndreyBelym for reply, unfortunately that didn't help, still same error.

Comment: Let's continue discussing this issue in the context of your GitHub thread - [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4612](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4612).

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issue and fixed it by replacing `chrome:headless` with `firefox:headless`.